# Loop thru list to update value in named cell and then run macro

Tags: vba, loops

I am stuck on a loop command.  I am trying to:

1) Copy the next ticker symbol from a list and into a named cell
2) run a couple of macros that will use the new value in the named cell
3) loop to select the next ticker symbol in the list and repeat to process until hitting a blank cell at the end of the list.

Below is my code, I get zippo; not even an error message when I run it.

```
Sub Loop_data1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
 Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")   ' ws with list of tickers
Dim Rng As Range        
Set Rng = Range("a2")       ' 1st row with ticker value

Range("Stock_ticker") = Rng  '  copy value selected from ticker list to named cell stock_ticker

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

Macro1
Macro2

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select     ' select next ticker by stepping down 1 row from present location

Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not so bad, but I see several problems in it:

- You don't set rng from ws (use of Range("a2") use the ActiveSheet)
- ActiveCell is not safe because you could change the selected cell in Macro1 or Macro2 and you won't see it without debug.

I propose the next changes

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng as range
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")   ' ws with list of tickers
Set rng = ws.Range("a2")       ' 1st row with ticker value

Range("Stock_ticker") = rng

' here you use ActiveCell, but no activeCell was selected
' set a range you manage yourself is safer
' I set the cell with the value of rng, but if you don't want this one, change to the needed value
Do Until IsEmpty(rng)
    ' If you wanted to use ActiveCell in Macro1 or 2, it's safer to pass rng thru parameters
    call Macro1
    call Macro2

    set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0) ' select next ticker by stepping down 1 row
Loop
```